# What is the equivalent of 'break' in q#?

Tags: break, q#

How would I break out of a loop when I meet a condition?
For example:

```
for (i in 0..10){
    if (i==3){
        // equivalent of break
     }
}
```

Comment: FYI: There is a https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no break in Q#; however, you can implement this behavior using [repeat-until-success loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-qr-statements#control-flow).

Q# is not a general-purpose language, and is designed to allow a lot of optimizations for when a program will be executed on a quantum device. Loops are one example of such design: if you know beforehand how many iterations your loop will do, use a for loop, if you need to iterate until some condition is met, use repeat-until-success loop.

Your example (which is not really a good example of why you'd need a break) would be written as something like this:

```
mutable i = 0;
repeat {
    set i = i + 1;
} until (i == 10 || i == 3)
fixup {
    ();
}
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit, features like `adjoint auto` require the compiler to compute how an operation acts when "run backwards." This is very difficult to do with the `break` keyword, such that it's helpful to use other control flow constructs instead.